# Connecting multiple scroll bars to scroll at once using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, scrollbars

I have split a very long (scrolling) table in shorter tables to allow scroll bars to be added at increments down the table. I have some script that allows a scroll bar at the top to match the scroll bar under the following table - but is there a way to link all the tables so they all scroll at the same time no matter what scroll bar you use?

So currently the top scroll bar and the first bottom scroll bar will control all scroll bars but the lower ones do not...

```js
$(function(){
 'use strict';
    $(".tableScrollTop").scroll(function(){
        $(".tableWide-wrapper")
            .scrollLeft($(".tableScrollTop").scrollLeft());
    });
    $(".tableWide-wrapper").scroll(function(){
        $(".tableScrollTop")
            .scrollLeft($(".tableWide-wrapper").scrollLeft());
    });
});
```

```css
.tableWide-wrapper {
 overflow-x: auto;
 border-right: 2px solid #797979;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}

.tableScrollTop {
 overflow-x: scroll;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 height:20px;
 width: 100%;
}

.tableWide {
 width: 1500px;
 table-layout: fixed;
 margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tableScrollTop"><div style="width:1500px; height:20px;"></div></div>
<div class="tableWide-wrapper" tabindex="0">
  <table class="table-2 tableWide">
    <tr>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
 </div>

<div class="tableWide-wrapper" tabindex="0">
  <table class="table-2 tableWide">
    <tr>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
 </div>

<div class="tableWide-wrapper" tabindex="0">
  <table class="table-2 tableWide">
    <tr>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force the `scrollLeft` of each of the tables to be the value of the `scrollLeft` of the current element that you scroll:

```js
$(function(){
    'use strict';
    $(".tableScrollTop,.tableWide-wrapper").scroll(function(){
        $(".tableWide-wrapper,.tableScrollTop")
            .scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
    });
});
```

```css
.tableWide-wrapper {
 overflow-x: auto;
 border-right: 2px solid #797979;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom:20px;
}

.tableScrollTop {
 overflow-x: scroll;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 height:20px;
 width: 100%;
}

.tableWide {
 width: 1500px;
 table-layout: fixed;
 margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tableScrollTop"><div style="width:1500px; height:20px;"></div></div>
<div class="tableWide-wrapper" tabindex="0">
  <table class="table-2 tableWide">
    <tr>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
 </div>

<div class="tableWide-wrapper" tabindex="0">
  <table class="table-2 tableWide">
    <tr>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
 </div>

<div class="tableWide-wrapper" tabindex="0">
  <table class="table-2 tableWide">
    <tr>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
      <td>table copy</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Here is the explanation:

`$(".tableScrollTop,.tableWide-wrapper").scroll` - once you scroll any element that is `tableScrollTop` class or `tableWide-wrapper` class run the following:

1. Find any element that has the `tableScrollTop` class or the `tableWide-wrapper` class - `$(".tableWide-wrapper,.tableScrollTop")`
2. For each element - set it's `scrollLeft` value to the `scrollLeft` value of the current element that was just scrolled: `$(this).scrollLeft()`

Comment: Perfect, thanks. ...and thanks for expelling it too - that really helps!

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer as correct (and a vote-up will also be appreciated :) ) thanks!

Comment: How do I do that? (I'm new to this site)